# POST via Ajax does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I looked now through a various number of StackOverflow pages and other websites - but can't find the correct solution for my problem. I try to post two values over to a php page via Post:

loginframe.php:

```
<form class="signin">
        <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-login" type="submit" value="login" id="btn-login">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

My js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-login").click(function(){

        var username = $("#inputUsername").val();
        var password = $("#inputPassword").val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: 'login.php',
            data: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

My login.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
    {
        echo $_POST['user'];
        echo $_POST['pass'];
    } else {
        include 'loginframe.php';
    }
```

This login.php is just to check now if the data is passed. That is absolutely not the case. It always opens loginframe.php...
I can't find the error - I appreciate your help! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Did you install firbug, here you can check response.

Comment: use data string as data="user=" + username + "&pass=" + password;

Comment: change your button type to <input type="button"  class="btn-login"  value="Sign in" id="btn-login">

Comment: is your ajax call completed before form got submit, i guess its not..??

Comment: Change "type" to "method" in ajax call, also add dataType: "html"

Comment: my point is what @Vicky has suggested..

Comment: your type is wrong. type="username" should be type="text"

Comment: Actually it is what ajax does. You have echoed some response and hence that response will be passed to your js succes. If you echo the values ajax dosent print it out for you. As far as i know this is how ajax is expected to behave. And also change your type: POST to method:POST as suggested by @SoftGuide

Comment: @tacovox The php opens loginframe.php again because that is the page from where the ajax post request is made.Hope this makes sense to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prevent default  method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn-login").click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault(); // this one prevents the default submission of the form

            var username = $("#inputUsername").val();
            var password = $("#inputPassword").val();

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: 'login.php',
                data: {
                    user: username,
                    pass: password
                },
                success: function(result)
                {
                    $("#result").html(result);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Applied your changes now as well as changing the button type as supposed --> now the button does not work at all... Something is really wrong there. [link](http://www.derkahler.de/trux/) Thats the page.

Comment: Its working bro.Check your console.Its because you forgot to add the result div.Add a div to your page with id result.
`<div id="result"></div>`

Comment: @AneeshRS his code was already working. :). He never checked the response instead waited for the echoed output